# Twitter Bootstrap messes up Google Chart Editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Chart Editor and Twitter Bootstrap 4 and I think they are not compatible.

Here is a jsfiddle where you can see the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bx4sgsrf/

The basic example for Google Chart:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['charteditor']});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadEditor);
    var chartEditor = null;

    function loadEditor() {
      // Create the chart to edit.
      var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         'chartType':'LineChart',
         'dataSourceUrl':'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ&pub=1',
         'query':'SELECT A,D WHERE D > 100 ORDER BY D',
         'options': {'title':'Population Density (people/km^2)', 'legend':'none'}
      });

      chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);
      chartEditor.openDialog(wrapper, {});
    }

    // On "OK" save the chart to a <div> on the page.
    function redrawChart(){
      chartEditor.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('vis_div'));
    }
```

without the Bootstrap 4, everything is fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3wk42Lb/

I need to use Bootstrap with Chart Editor and they are not working together, what is causing this issue?

Comment: The code the chart is outputting includes `modal-dialog` which aligns with Bootstrap's Modal component. Can you adjust that classname?